# Is there a CodeMap alternative for Visual Studio Professional

Tags: visual-studio-2012, code-map

I just saw a [great video about CodeMap](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Visual-Studio-2012-Premium-and-Ultimate-Overview/Visual-Studio-Ultimate-2012-Understanding-complex-code-with-Code-Map-ENU) but to be able to create a CodeMap you need the Ultimate Edition of Visual Studio. **Are there any free alternatives to CodeMap for Professioanl Edition?** Even something outside of Visual Studio would be nice.

Comment: if sb knows - let me know! I am also looking for something like this. I know that I have found http://codemap.kr/ for IDAPro https://www.hex-rays.com, but... still lots to be found I think

Comment: For sake we need a free alternative for commercial use. Been 4 years now, and still nothing?

Comment: This question IMHO should not be closed, as it has gathered lot may votes because we all would like to know the answer and what site is better than SO to answer this kind of questions

Answer (score 6):

For some use cases, you can try the [Quick Diagram Tool for C#](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=FerencVizkeleti.QuickDiagramToolforC).

Comment: Worth noting that the news section states:
"The next version of this tool will no longer be free. It will become a commercial product to finance the ongoing efforts of development."

Comment: This is an old posting but possibly someone who knows can answer. Seems that this plugin does work with vs2017 and vs2019 preview but not vs2019 community ed.

Comment: not available in 2022 anymore

Comment: Paid, but free trial for 2022